# paraphrasing , better alternatives for "traditional societies" and "caring for children"

Tags: grammar, synonyms, paraphrasing

As you might know, paraphrasing is very important in the introduction section of the IELTS writing, task2. Here I tried to paraphrase a sentence and wanted to know your opinion on that. Do you have better ideas?

You can see the original sentence below :

> In many traditional societies, caring for the children is only the mother's responsibility.

This is the way I paraphrased the sentence :

> There is a widely held view in many traditional and religious communities that mother is the only family member who must shoulder the responsibility of taking care of the children.

I used *"traditional and religious communities"* for *"traditional societies"* , do you have better alternatives for that?

And instead of "caring for the children" , I used "Taking care of the children" , do you have better ideas for that as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Traditional societies"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_society) is an official term, and therefore replacing it or paraphrasing it does *not* result in the same meaning. That phrase should be left as-is.

"Taking care of the children" is a valid paraphrase of "caring for the children."